# Update my Ubuntu version from Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: upgrade, versions

I do not know how to update my Ubuntu version from 13.04 to 17.04 I tried using software center but I could not do it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve what you want here, is getting an USB-Stick prepared with the version you want to upgrade to.

Since 13.04 went EOL in January 27, 2014 it is unlikely that you will get a proper upgrade process done. Needless to say that you would to do a really mass of upgrades (from 13.04 to 13.10 to 14.04 to 14.10 ... and so on).

I also would suggest getting a version which not shortly will run out of lifetime like 17.04 is going to (EOL date for it is January 2018). Instead go for a LTS (long term support) release of Ubuntu. The current LTS is 16.04 and the next will be 18.04, to be released April next year. (Kudos to [MichaelBay](https://askubuntu.com/users/692175/michaelbay) who pointed this out in coments)

To avoid complications I would as well suggest a backup of your data and a fresh clean install if whatever version you choose.

Comment: Prefer LTS releases for stability and longevity of support. The current LTS is 16.04 and the next will be 18.04, to be released April next year.

Comment: @MichaelBay incorporated it into the answer.